# Regex redirect of wordpress blog from subdomain to domain

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect the WordPress blog post from old to new domain.
We had a blog on subdomain  `http://blog.domain.xyz/` and after the migration is on main domain  `https://www.domain.xyz/`

On the old blog, URL of the blog post was:
`http://blog.domain.xyz/2020/03/25/post-name`  
(part `/2020/03/25/` is just an example of date)
now I need it to redirect to: 
`https://www.domain.xyz/post-name`

I matched with regex domain and date part:

```
http\:\/\/blog.domain.xyz\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/
```

I know how to redirect manually all posts one by one, but there are more than 1000 posts, so this is not an option.

I can't figure out how to take `post-name` part and apply it to the new domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like the following.

```
RewriteRule ^/\d+/\d+/\d+/(.*)$ https://www.domain.xyz/$1 [R=301,L]

// ^/ start at the root
// \d+/\d+/\d+/ match date folders like 2020/03/25/
// (.*) the part we want to keep "some-slug"
// $ end of match
// $1 put the part we want to keep here "some-slug"
```

Basically matching any urls with /2020/03/25/post-name and redirects to https://www.domain.xyz/post-name.

Note: this assumes you're adding the redirect at the old domain.

Comment: Thanks mikerojas
In the meantime, I figured it out and did it similarly as you did.

I edited my question and added answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I figured it out:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain.xyz$ 
  RewriteRule \d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}(.*)$ https://www.domain.xyz$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`